# Unable to get ckEditor in partailview

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Am working on asp.net MVC3. I need to use ckeditor in a partail view.

IN Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult Compose()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

and my view contains

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

 <%: Html.TextArea("Body", signature , new { @class = "ckeditor", rows = "5", cols = "15"})%> 

<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3, the concept should be the same

First import all the library to the root folder of your project
otherwise some dependencies for file will be missing

Include this js file to your view

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/ckeditor.js")"></script>
```

In Your controller do the following

```
public PartialViewResult Compose(){
    return PartialView("CKeditor");
}
```

In Your view load the partial view with the script

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
     @Html.TextArea("body", new { @id = "editor1", name = "editor1", rows = "30", cols = "100" })
}

<script type="text/javascript">
     CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
</script>
```

[Download the Source Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lumq81eht895tbv/CKEditor.rar)